# Instantiate User Control with Custom Attributes

Tags: c#, controls

My User Control has the following properties:

```
private String _requestIP;
public String RequestIP
{
     get { return _requestIP; }
     set { _requestIP = value; }
}
```

When adding a instance of the Control to an aspx page at design time it's easy to assign the attributes which can be utilized in the codebehind file...

```
<uc:Item ID="Testing" runat="server" RequestIP="127.0.0.1" />
```

However, if I try to create the control at runtime in the aspx.cs file, how am I able to assign values to these attributes?

```
Control ItemX = (Control)Page.LoadControl("/controls/item.ascx");
```

There is no ItemX.Attributes.Add() method which I would expect to be there, and no ItemX.RequestIP property to set.

Is there a way to set this dynamically in the aspx page using <%= Users_IP_Address %> tags or some other method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you just need to cast it to the appropriate type (whatever the class name of your user control is).

Comment: Aha! Instead of Control.  I think I have a naming conflict to sort out.  Thanks!

Comment: Many thanks!  I've been trying to figure this out for days.  :)